# Cocos2d-js: Error Message: "Invalid Native Object" using runAction()

Tags: android, cocos2d-js

I get some "Invalid Native Object"-errors in Android (Nexus 5, Android 4.4.4). In the browser version there are no errors.

I put the code part of my app into a fresh helloworld app. Line 59, where the error appears is marked below.
This is the logcat message from ADB:

> D/cocos2d-x debug info(32165): jsb: ERROR: File /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_actions/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/../../js-bindings/bindings/auto/jsb_cocos2dx_auto.cpp: Line: 3955, Function: js_cocos2dx_Node_runAction
>   D/cocos2d-x debug info(32165): Invalid Native Object
>   D/cocos2d-x debug info(32165): JS: assets/src/app.js:59:Error: Invalid Native Object
>   D/cocos2d-x debug info(32165):

This is the code.

> var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
>       sprite:null,
>       ctor:function () {
>
> ```
>   var self = this;
>     //////////////////////////////
>     // 1. super init first
>     this._super();
>
>     /////////////////////////////
>     // 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
>     //    you may modify it.
>     // ask director the window size
>     var size = cc.director.getWinSize();
>
>   // Load sprite frames to frame cache, add texture node
>     cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.murbiks_plist);
>     var murbiksImages  = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(cc.textureCache.addImage(res.murbiks_png));
>   self.addChild(murbiksImages);
>
>   var anims = {};
>   var loadFrames = function(name,cnt) {
>       var frames = [];
>       for (var i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {
>           str = name + (i < 10 ? ("0" + i) : i);
>           frames.push(cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str));           
>       }
>       var anim = cc.Animation.create(frames, 0.06);
>       anim.retain();
>       anims[name] = cc.animate(anim);
>   }
>
>   loadFrames("mostafa_fly",9);
>   loadFrames("mostafa_land",7);
>
>     var mostafa = cc.Sprite.create(res.murbiks_single_png);        
>     mostafa.attr({
>       x: 0,
>       y: 0,
>       scale: 1.9,
>       rotation: 0
>   });
>     mostafa.retain();
>   self.addChild(mostafa, 5);
>
>   var animAction = mostafa.runAction(cc.repeatForever(anims.mostafa_fly)),
>   bezierMostafa = [
>       cc.p(0,0),
>         cc.p(200,520),
>         cc.p(500,220)
>   ];
>
>   var mostafaAction = mostafa.runAction(
>           cc.sequence(
>               cc.bezierTo(2.5, bezierMostafa),
>               cc.callFunc(function() {
>               self.stopAction(animAction);
>                   animAction = mostafa.runAction(anims.mostafa_land); // LINE 59, INVALID NATIVE OBJECT
>               })
>           )
>       ); 
>
>    return true;
> ```
>
> }
>    });

What could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

murbiksImages should call retain() too

generally, "invalid native object" means some object is deleted in native code, which usually happens when object didn't call retain

and, SpriteBatchNode is deprecated in cocos2d-x3.0

you'd better not use it, it will be deprecated in cocos2d-js too

Comment: Thanks! I just threw out SpriteBatchNode and added the line anims[name].retain(); after anims[name] = cc.animate(anim); Then it worked!